# Access spring boot Rest endpoint with a hardcoded token?

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to expose an REST GET endpoint which allows downloading a file as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/downloadFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void downloadResource(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String name) {
    downloadService.flushFile(response, name);
}
```

The Security config looks as below currently:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/v1/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().rememberMe();
    http.httpBasic();
}
```

**Question:** : How to enable a hard coded token, so the client javascript can include it in every request it sends?

Currently there is no security token passed when calling the GET service.

```
window.open("http://localhost:8080/DownloadMS/v1/downloadFile?fileName=abc_test");
```

**Solutions Tried:** I've tried using a username and password when calling the GET service as below. This is potentially bad since the password is seen clearly upon page inspect (in all the browsers).

```
window.open("http://username:password@localhost:8080/DownloadMS/v1/downloadFile?fileName=abc_test");
```

Thanks

Comment: you can just use spring security basic auth if you are just testing

Comment: What do you mean with "hardcoded" token? -> Usually a token, like a `JWT`, is not static or even "hardcoded" but changes time to time.

Comment: @git-flo Do you have an example to achieve that in spring boot? In this case, there will be 2 calls. One for getting the token, second one to pass it with.

Comment: If this is what you want to achieve, I can write you an qualified answer.

Comment: @git-flo YEs, this is exactly what I need. FYI, I'm using a YML file to read properties. 

I've spend much time in configuring a hard token requirement, appreciate a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your usecase there are various ways to achieve a token-based authentication. Most common is `OAuth2`. The `spring-security-oauth2` together with the `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` enables you to easy setup an `OAuth2` suitable application. For example it brings along a `ResourceServer` and `AuthorizationServer`. You can find the official Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/).

Another good tutorial can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt). It makes heavy use of the `spring-security-jwt` package. Even though you are looking for a small solution and a hardcoded token would be enough, I strongly recommend to use a implementation of `AuthorizationServer` and `ResourceServer` for your application. Otherwise the token secured solution would not be better than a password secured solution.

Comment: I was able to use a random generated String as a token to pass back from Service to javascript. 

I'll add the best approach of Oauth in the next development iteration! It was a great read. 

Thanks